# Wrong output with the following C code

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int l,m,q,j;
    char option;
    scanf("%d",&q);
    printf("%d\n",q);
    for(j=0;j<q;j++){
        scanf("%c %d %d",&option,&l,&m);
        printf("%c %d %d",option,l,m);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3(Input)
3
C 1 4(Input)

 0 -374066224C 1 4
```

What is wrong with the above code? It is not giving the expected output.

Comment: What is your *expected* output?

Comment: What **is** the expected output? Did you try to debug it? Seems lie a homework-related problem...

Comment: @Levon Its not a homework, I tried debugging using gdb but no use. The expected output should be the same as input

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is still a newline character in the input stream from the initial `scanf()` (and subsequent `scanf()`s): this will be assigned to `option` and the subsequent `int` assignments will fail as `C`  is not an `int`, meaning `l` and `m` are uninitialised `int` variables.

To skip it add a leading space character to the format specifier of the `scanf()` within the `for` loop:

```
scanf(" %c %d %d",&option,&l,&m);
    /* ^ */
```

The return value of `scanf()` is the number of successful assignments made: check it to ensure `3` assignments are made.

```
if (3 == scanf(" %c %d %d",&option,&l,&m))
{
    /* Valid input. */
}
```

Comment: That solved the problem but could you explain why there is a newline character please

Comment: @sachinirukula, when the user enters the number they type `3` and hit return. The return inserts a new line character into the input stream. The new line character is not consumed by the `scanf()`, leaving it in the input stream.

Comment: @sachinirukula The reason why goes back to the ancient things called typewriters. When you pressed their equivalent to enter, the machine did a carriage return (back to the left-most side of the paper) and then it changed to a new line. Windows works the same. Windows text files even end each row with the ASCII symbols '\r' (ASCII 13) '\n' (ASCII 10), they are called carriage return and line feed respectively.

Comment: For the record, the reason why the initial space solves the problem is this section of the standard: 7.21.6.2/5 (scanf functions) "A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails."

Answer (score 2):

Every time you prompt the user for an input, they will write it and then press enter. Enter leaves a line feed character in the input buffer. You must discard it before asking for a character input, or it will end up in your character variable.

The easy but blunt solution is this:

```
scanf("%d",&q); getchar();
printf("%d\n",q);
for(j=0;j<q;j++){
    scanf("%c %d %d",&option,&l,&m); getchar();
    printf("%c %d %d",option,l,m);
}
```

(I'm pretty sure there is a C FAQ for this somewhere but I can't find the link.)

Comment: hmjd's solution is far prettier, so I would go with that.